# Unable to create google project with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm following the [Google GKE and SQL with terraform](https://medium.com/@mudrii/google-gke-and-sql-with-terraform-294fb84061) tutorial
But I'm not able to create a *google_project.project*.
I have tried both as the owner of the project and as the service described in the tutorial. Both attempts end with this error:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_project.project: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_project.project: error creating project terraform-dev-357aa670 
 (terraform-dev): googleapi: Error 403: User is not authorized., forbidden. 
  If you received a 403 error, make sure 
  you have the `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` permission
```

I would think that I had the correct permissions as the project owner, but apparently not.

**Here's how I created the service account:**

```
$ gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding ${TF_VAR_org_id} \                                (gke_my-domain-218910_europe-west1-b_my-domain-vpc-native/default)
> --member serviceAccount:terraform@${TF_ADMIN}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
> --role roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator
Updated IAM policy for organization [00000].
bindings:
- members:
  - domain:my-domain.no
  role: roles/billing.creator
- members:
  - serviceAccount:terraform@my-domain-terraform-admin-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:terraform@my-domain-terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/billing.user
- members:
  - domain:min-familie.no
  - serviceAccount:terraform@my-domain-terraform-admin-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:terraform@my-domain-terraform-admin.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator
etag: BwWJxJTDnQs=
version: 19d
```

Creating a project "manually" works.
`$ gcloud projects create ${TF_ADMIN}`.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe try and create a project using the gcloud command from the command line and see if you can perform that task without going near terraform ... see  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create folders and projects, your account need to have the respective permissions and, of course you need to make sure that you are using the right account.

First make sure the user has the right permissions:

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID --member=user:your@email.com --role=roles/billing.admin
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID --member=user:your@email.com --role=roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID --member=user:your@email.com --role=roles/resourcemanager.folderCreator
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID --member=user:your@email.com --role=roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator
```

Then make sure you set the application defaults and login to exactly this account:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The set a project that the API calls will be billed to by default. Read more about this [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project).  If you don't set this, you might get a quota error when you run `terraform apply`.

```
gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project SOME_BILLING_PROJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problem!

Steps that solved this problem for me:

1. Downloaded the key for that Service Account (Using GCP Console) to : /Users/johndoe/sa.json
2. export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/johndoe/factory.json
3. terraform apply

Hope this works for you.

Found the solution from Seth Fargo here:
https://github.com/sethvargo/vault-on-gke/issues/16